# AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'hexdigest'

Tags: python-3.x, hex, hashlib

I wrote the following code but the problem is that I recieved an error (`AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'hexdigest'`)
the error syntax doesn't work

```
import requests
import hashlib 

def request_api_data (query_char):
    url = 'https://api.pwnedpasswords.com/range/'+ query_char
    res = requests.get(url)
    if res.status_code != 200:
        print('it is an error')
        #raise RuntimeError(f'Error fetching: {res.status_code}, check api and try again')
        return res
request_api_data('123')

def pwned_api_check(password):
    sha1password= hashlib.sha1(password.encode('utf-8').hexdigest().upper())
    
    print (sha1password)

    #return sha1password

pwned_api_check('123')
```

Why does this error occur and how do I fix it??

Comment: Please rename the question to something like: "hashlib error: AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'hexdigest'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a parenthesis after `hashlib.sha1(password.encode('utf-8')`, so `hexdigest().upper()` is called on it.

The following code works for me:

```
hashlib.sha1(password.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest().upper()
```

Answer (score 0):

I was taking the same class as you and got the same error. The parenthesis are in the wrong place.

```py
sha1password = hashlib.sha1(password.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest().upper()
```

Comment: This is the same solution as in the accepted answer. When answering older questions that already have answers, please make sure you provide either a novel solution or a significantly better explanation than existing answers. Remember to review all existing answers first.